# I can't turn off ssl2 and ssl3 and remove medium cipher strengths

Tags: ssl, centos6

I am editing my ssl.conf file (The only ssl.conf file on the server) to have the following settings.

```
#SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
SSLProtocol TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

#SSLCipherSuite DEFAULT:!EXP:!DES:!IDEA:!SEED:+3DES
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-S$
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

but when I restart httpd and run a scan against the server it still shows the following:
SSL Version 2 and 3 Protocol Detection
SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported
SSL 64-bit Block Size Cipher Suites Supported (SWEET32)

What am I doing wrong here?

I have even run the following to check I do not have a duplicate command

```
sudo grep -rin "SSLProtocol" /etc/*
```

I don't

Any advice on how to remove these risks would be gratefully received

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this ssl.conf is included in the main server configuration?

Comment: How can you tell? If I put something wrong in ssl.conf the httpd service fails to load so it looks like the service is reading the file

Comment: Yes, this was a proper way to check that the file gets actually loaded. And are you sure that this is actually the server you test against and not some reverse proxy in front of it or similar? As for Sweet32 - you have explicitly 3DES enabled which makes this attack possible. And could you maybe add an explicit `-all` at the beginning of the SSLProtocol?

Comment: I've added a -all and the same results

Comment: SSLProtocol -all TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

Comment: Could there be some other service running or config which overrides the ssl.conf? I have checked to see if SSLProtocol is set anywhere else but the result comes back as ssl.conf

Comment: I really wonder why SLv2 is reported as enabled. Modern systems usually don't even have SSLv2 support in the OpenSSL library anymore. What kind of system, OpenSSL version and Apache version is this (detailed version numbers)?

Comment: I'm running openssl v 1.0.1e 57.el6 and 2.2.15 59.el6.centos of httpd

Comment: and that's on centos 6.8

Comment: pretty old software then which has probable still SSLv2 support. Have you looked into Apache error log in case it is ignoring some options?

Comment: Nothing hits the log when I run the a test

Comment: So I am running the following from another system openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 -ssl2

Comment: It's more that I've expected such log messages on startup of Apache, i.e. that it will ignore some configuration settings when reading the config. But if you don't see any messages in the error log I don't know either what's wrong with your setup - it's impossible to reproduce for me to further debug it.

Comment: I think it is worth me trying later versions of httpd and openssl. Are there any other packages which are involved that I would need to look at?

Comment: I don't know if there is anything newer pre-packaged for CentOS 6.8

Comment: I may need to compile my own although I am not convinced this is will fix the problem

Comment: What role does mod_ssl play? If I remove this rpm does this help? Sorry for what sounds like a dumb question

Comment: mod_ssl is the module for Apache which implements the TLS interface. Removing it will make Apache not be able to handle HTTPS anymore.

Comment: Is there any specific config file for this or is it httpd.conf I am struggling to locate why the config in ssl.conf is being ignored or overwritten

Comment: Sorry, but the system looks really strange for me and based on the few information it is impossible for me to figure out what is really going on there, which means I cannot help anymore.